# Is there a way to get a bigger cursor on the login screen on Monterey

Tags: macos, monterey, system-settings, accessibility, cursor

I use a 43" tv as my main screen running 1800 x 2800 pixels.  On my account, I've set the cursor larger and with red edges to make it easier to find.

But the login screen still has the default small cursor.

Is there a way to make the cursor on the login screen larger?

It would be ok, if the whole display was running at say 1200 x 1800 and everything was larger and then it resent to my preferences later.

But I don't know how to do that either.

Comment: Nope, not before log in. The preferences setting kick in after log in